# Load treelistview from datasource with hardcoded root nodes on treelistview

Tags: c#, devexpress, treelistview

.
Could you please provide me a code sample showing how to load a treelistview from database​ with hardcoded root nodes on treelistview.

I have shared the link below of a sample preview of the tree I am in need of. Rootnodes are hardcoded and I want the child nodes to be populated from a database.

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=qnr212&s=5#.Upl6WsSnrh0

Please shed some light here.

Thanks
Rahul​

Answer (score 0):

To populate a `XtraTreeList`, you can simply do this :

```
List<UserDefiniedClass> myListOfObjects = new List<UserDefiniedClass>();
// Here, you could populate your list
// ...
myTreeList.DataSource = myListOfObjects;
```

According to the child / parent relationship, when defining your class `UserDefiniedClass`, you have to add two public fields, which are : `ID` and `ParentID` (which are of type `int`).

When you build your list of objects, make sure that :

- You affect a different `ID` for each record
- You affect the parent `ID` as the child's `ParentID`
- You don't affect the `ParentID` field if the node does not have a parent.

Hope that helps !